Spring Vault: Why @VaultPropertySource not getting highest precedence?
Context
trying to fetch secrets from Hashicorp Vault, instead of hardcoding in properties file
What I have tried
I am following Spring Vault docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/reference/vault/propertysource.html#_registering_vaultpropertysource
Where it says

VaultPropertySource has been added with highest precedence in the search. If it contains a ´foo` property, it will be detected and returned ahead of any foo property in any other PropertySource.

However, when used in conjunction with spring cloud vault KV backend, it trumps @VaultPropertySource annotation from spring-vault-core, and my springboot application starts with properties obtained by spring-cloud-vault, intead of @VaultPropertySource as the presendence info in the docs suggest
Evidence:
spring-cloud-vault config in application.yml
  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secret
        application-name: receiver
      authentication: token
      #      this is set in intelliJ run configuration > environment variable section
      token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}
      uri: http://127.0.0.1:8200

Below are screenshots from actuator/env

@VaultPropertySource loaded values skipped
I am using spring Configuration and @VaultPropertySource like below
@Configuration
@VaultPropertySource("receiver/db")
class VaultConfig() { ... }


